# How to delete the last row in a dynamic web table

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to delete the last row in a dynamic web table. I am using selenium *C#*. Below is my code

```
IWebElement deleteButton = element.find("XPath", "html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/form/div/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[1]/input", driver);
```

`tr[12]` is the last row and able to delete now. But each time I need to update the number. Without changing the number how to change the code.

Please help me on this query.

Comment: is this table based on a list/map in some backend or directly pulled data from DB? If there is a list in background just delete the element there and reload the needed div-box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following xpath, It may works for you.

```
html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/form/div/table/tbody/tr[last()]/td[1]/input
```

in code,

```
IWebElement deleteButton = element.find("XPath", "html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/form/div/table/tbody/tr[last()]/td[1]/input", driver);
```

Comment: Thank you Murthi. The above code is working, but in the UI I have add icon in the last row. So I need to delete the last before row, can you please help me.

Comment: you can use last()-1 in the xpath like html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/form/div/table/tbody/tr[last()]/td[last()-1]/input

Comment: I have update the above code but it is the not deleting the record and the test case is passed.

Comment: IWebElement deleteButton = element.find("XPath", "html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/form/div/table/tbody/tr[last()]/td[last()-1]/input", driver);
                deleteButton = Utility.ScrollToView(driver, deleteButton);

                if (Utility.isElementDisplayed(deleteButton))
                {
                    Utility.Click(deleteButton);
                    Console.WriteLine("INSIDE DELETE LOOP");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("NO CUSTOM STATUSES AVAILABLE TO BE DELETED ---> ");

Comment: script is going to else condition and unable to find the delete icon

Comment: sorry, xpath should be html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/form/div/table/tbody/tr[last()-1]/‌​td[1]/input

Comment: Hi Murthi, can you please check my question and provide me a solution?. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132085/how-to-execute-the-unit-test-cases-parallel-in-visual-studio-2015/47132277#47132277