# How to execute the unit test cases parallel in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, selenium

I am new to automation testing and using Selenium C# in Visual studio 2015. I have 36 test cases and it took 38 minutes to complete the test run. To reduce the test time i am looking for parallel test run. In my test configuration i have used MSTet.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework. I have searched for related topics and found that to add runsetting file. I have added the same but the test not running parallel. Can any once help me on my request or share any document to achieve my request. Please help me on this request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just use the "run tests in parallel" option in the VS Test Explorer.

[image]

Comment: Yes, i have used this option but only one test case is executing at a time.

Comment: In MSTest "Run test in parallel" mean "Run test project in parallel" - it will execute in parallel only tests of different test projects. For running every test in parallel, consider using XUnit as test framework, where every test method executed in parallel by default.

Comment: Thank you Fabio. So i have to uninstall the MSTest framework and install XUnit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62199786/5349104

I faced the same issue. Refer the above link, it works with MSTest itself. We need enable workers at assembly level to run tests parallelly within a project. Note the comment in that answer as well.